# Como mudar a cor do link depois que o link foi acessado?

Tags: html, css

Usando `bootstrap`

```
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <ul  class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item text-left"><strong>QUESTIONÁRIO</strong></li>
                <li class="list-group-item text-left"><a href="<?php echo URL ?>formulario?bloco=1" ></a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-grey text-left"><a href="<?php echo URL ?>formulario?bloco=2" onclick="page()">PATROCINADORES E INSTITUIDORES</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item text-left"><a href="<?php echo URL ?>formulario?bloco=3">C</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-grey text-left"><a href="<?php echo URL ?>formulario/passivo?bloco=4"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

tentei usar :

```
a:visited {
    color: pink;
}
```

todos os links ficam rosa, mesmo os visitados.

Comment: Eles ficaram rosas provavelmente porque você já clicou neles, tente abrir em uma sessão icógnita do seu navegador

Answer (score 2):

Customizando seu elemento através do seletor **:visited**, em sua folha de estilos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

a.green:visited {
    color: green;
}
a.black:visited {
    color: black;
}
a.red:visited {
    color: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a class="green" href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/">SOPT</a><br>
<a class ="black"href="http:/http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/34755/denalioasis">denalioasis</a><br>
<a class="red" href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/45437/magichat">MagicHat</a>

<p><b>Clico mudou ! GL, ;)</b></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Se quer customizar 1 a 1, tem de colocar um identificador para cada ou uma classe(id="identificador" ou class="suaClasse")